# Bash - Lock directory for deletion while script is running

Tags: bash, locking, delete-file

I would like to lock a directory while a Bash script is running and make sure it's not locked anymore when the script dies.

My script creates a directory, and I want to try deleting it, if it I can't delete it then it means it's locked. If it's not locked it should create the directory.

```sh
rm "$dir_path" > /dev/null 2>&1

if [ -d "$dir_path" ]; then
   exit 0
fi

cp -r "$template_dir" "$dir_path"

# Lock directory
#LOCK "$dir_path"
# flock --exclusive --nonblock "$app_apex_path" # flock: bad file descriptor


# When script ends the lock is automatically removed without need to do any cleanup
# this is necessary because if for example in case of power failure the dir would still
# be locked on next boot.
```

I have looked into `flock` but it doesn't seem to work like this.

Comment: It is unclear: Is the problem that the _locking_  does not work, or is the problem that the _removal_  of the lock does not work?

Comment: @user1934428 The lock doesn't work. And even if it works as I understand one can still delete the directory even if it has the lock. So I think `flock` is not the solution.

Comment: If both competing processes use `flock`, I think this is a possible solution (unless you are locking accross the network). I suggest that you split your problem into two question: One shows a minimal example of two scripts which do the locking, and how you verify that locking does not work, and after this you ask a new question about removing the locks, if there is still an open problem. Also, it would be helpful to specify your platform.

Comment: If I understand well, you are using `locking` as indication that `dir_path` is being used. Can you use `existence` of `dir_path` as indication that it's being used ?

Comment: Ah, I just see that you invoke `flock` in the wrong way. See the flock man-page: With a single argument, this argument can't be a path name, but must be a file descriptor.

Comment: @Philippe I can't use any of those because if there's a reboot / shutdown the directory will still be there even though there's no script using it. I looked into `flock` exactly because as I understand it releases the lock automatically when script exits and it's not there after a reboot.

Comment: Is it possible to create a lock file and maintain it locked while the Bash script is running? I think this would solve my problem. If I run another instance I can check if it's locked and quit.

Comment: It seems `dir_path` is a transicent directory, you can create it in /tmp, so it's not there after reboot.

Comment: @Philippe using `/tmp` seems a good idea, will try that.

Comment: You may be expecting mandatory locking in an environment with advisory locking only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here’s an example with advisory locking, which works fine as long as all participating scripts follow the same protocol.

```sh
set -e

if ! mkdir '/tmp/my-magic-lock'; then
  exit 1  # Report an error, maybe?
fi
trap "rmdir '/tmp/my-magic-lock'" EXIT

# We hold the advisory lock now.
rm -Rf "$dir_path"
cp -a "$template_dir" "$dir_path"
```

As a side note, if I were to tackle this situation, I would simply make `$template_dir` and `$dir_path` Btrfs subvolumes and use snapshots instead of copies:

```
set -e
btrfs subvolume delete "$dir_path"
btrfs subvolume snapshot "$template_dir" "$dir_path"
```

This^^^ is way more efficient, “atomic” (in a number of beneficial ways), copy-on-write and also resilient towards multiple concurrent replacement attempts of the same kind, yielding a correct state once all attempts finish.